# How do I make browser show domain name when I approach my website with ip address?

Tags: node.js, web, dns

I mapped my DNS so that if I type `example.com`, which is my domain name, in the address bar of browser then it redirects to the ip address of my website, `192.0.2.111` (for example), correctly.  This way, the browser shows `example.com` in its address bar.

However, if I type `192.0.2.111`, which is the IP address for my website, then the browser shows `192.0.2.111` in its address bar, instead of showing `example.com`.

Is there a way so that the browser shows `example.com` (my domain name) in its address bar when I access my website with its IP address?

There must be a way since other websites work that way, but I could not find a solution.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming but 1) there is no redirection in the DNS; for what you look at the DNS just maps a name to an IP address 2) especially with HTTPS using URLs with IP addresses instead of hostnames is not recommanded at all and 3) so why do you want to type the IP address? but 4) You can configure your webserver to redirect `http://192.0.2.111/` to `http://www.example.com/` if you so witch. For Apache look at the redirect module or in general "rewriting rules". However I really think your time and energy are better not to take care of that.

Comment: Very few websites will work correctly with IP addresses in URLs because of mass virtual hosting (a single IP address can host thousand of different hostnames and websites). For HTTPS it is even worse as the certificate will need to have this IP address as validated resource, which is possible but far more complicated/rare than hostnames.

Comment: Thank you Patrick.  I think your 4th point about setting the web server to redirect the ip address to domain name address would be the solution I was looking for.

Comment: I started having this question as I was having an auth problem for my Single Page Application website, where my auth token is sent from 192.0.2.111 and it does not work when user access the website from example.com.  My interim solution for this was to send the auth token from example.com (instead of from 192.0.2.111), but I thought it would be best if I could somehow make the auth token to be valid regardless of whether user approached from ip address or domain name address.

Comment: In production, your website will only be available through a name most probably, not an IP address (because of virtual hosting, many names on single IP).

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, Patrick.  Seems like putting works to live production requires its own know-how and experience.